# Bamboo plugin for cucumber reports?

Tags: java, ruby, cucumber, bamboo, cucumber-jvm

I have used Cucumber with Jenkins in the past and `jenkins-cucumber-jvm-reports-plugin-java` is fantastic. All I need to do is to generate a cucumber `json` output to get a beautiful report.

My new project uses Bamboo and I could not find anything similar or atleast something closer.  Has any one have experience using Cucumber and Bamboo? Could use some helpful pointers. As this exercise is POC, either `Ruby` or `Java` would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that this was asked a long time ago. Not sure whether it is still valid but here is my experience with the same problem.
In my project we are using cucumber with bamboo and report generationn is also vital for us.

We found that the [Cucumber Report Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.hindsighttesting.behave.cucumber-bamboo-plugin) for bamboo is not sufficient for us so we moved to the [Cucumber Reporting](http://www.masterthought.net/section/cucumber-reporting) tool from MasterThought. As I see this is the exact same thing that the jenkins-cucumber-jvm-reports-plugin-java is using.

To utilize this in Bamboo we are calling it directly through maven after we have executed our tests during our build but there is also a maven-cucumber-reporting-mojo which can be used if you want to configure it through maven (we haven't used this because at that point it supported only one json input and we had hundreds of jsons but it's possible that this functionality was added in the mean time).

We are setting the generated html based output as artifact for our build so we can access the nice reports in bamboo for every build.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Csaba, can you put down your steps how you configured. Thanks